# How to do module resolution in typescript to output for node?

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsc

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "allowJs": false,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["dom", "es6", "es5", "es2017", "esnext.asynciterable"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "paths": {
      "src/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "declaration": true,
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "exclude": ["dist"],
  "include": [ "src"]
}
```

**Original Folder structure**

```
src /
  util/
    getSomething.ts
  index.ts
```

**Output Folder structure**

```
dist /
  util/
    getSomething.js
  index.js
```

**index.ts**

```
import getSomething from 'src/util/getSomething';
```

**package.json script**

```
{
"build": "tsc && tspath -f",
"start": "node dist/index.js"
}
```

The build works but when I run start I get error.
Is there a way to have a root based module resolution?
I followed this example (just replacing ~ with src) and it is giving me this problem.
Unless there is an alternative solution to tspath.
https://haseebmajid.dev/blog/better-imports-with-babel-tspath

Note: I am using windows 10.

```
npm start
```

> Error: Cannot find module './src\util\getSomething'
> Require stack:
> c:\apps\example-typescript-node\dist\index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered here:
https://github.com/duffman/tspath/issues/33

I have resolved my problem. I had to ensure my rootDir was ./ not src.
Then targeting index.js inside dist/src/ not dist/

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "./"
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
"build": "tsc && tspath -f",
"start": "node dist/src/index.js"
}
```